# Spring Filter added to specific RestController

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters, spring-restcontroller, spring-filter

I have a `@RestController` and I want to add to it a Spring Filter to add a check before processing request that extends `OncePerRequestFilter`

Also I don't want to add it to all controllers, my last resort is to add it to general `WebApplicationInitializer`'s `onStartup` on **specific path**:

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    FilterRegistration corsFilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("CorsFilter", CorsFilter.class);
   corsFilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/servlet/cors/*");
```

Is there other way to connect Spring Filter to specific Spring RestController?

Is it wrong using filter over interceptor in Spring REST?

Should filter be connected to URLs only?

Comment: What is this job you want this filter to do?

Comment: @chrylis IP whitelist

Comment: In that case, an interceptor would be a lot better option. You can even use a custom annotation like `@RequiresWhitelistedIp` to identify which controller methods should be advised.

Comment: @chrylis Isn't a filter defined at the start of the process more intuitive/clear?

Comment: The start of what process? A normal servlet-based request has so many levels of filters and dispatch anyway that you really don't gain anything. And as you have seen, it's not at all simple to connect a servlet filter to a Spring MVC controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@WebFilter annotation`.

Example:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "Filter", urlPatterns = { "/filter/*" })
public class WebFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
         .......
    }

   .......
  }
```

Comment: But I want to connect to RestControllers and not URLs

Comment: Filters are use url patterns. If you connect via class, you can use interceptor or aspect.

Comment: Actually I can't use it because I need `HttpServletRequest`